# Override get-only property in swift

Tags: swift

I have a *property* declared in parent class:

```
var textLabel: UILabel! { get }
```

Is it possible to make it writable in subclass?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes it is possible to make it writable in a subclass. However, since it is a computed property, you will more than likely have to add another stored property to hold the new value you are assigning. I used strings to illustrate below:

```
class Parent {
    var text: String {
        get {
            return "Parent"
        }
    }
}

class Child: Parent {
    var _text: String = "Child"
    override var text: String {
        get {
            return _text
        }
        set {
            self._text = newValue
        }
    }
}

let child = Child()
child.text = "New String"
```